# How to pass on all the items automatically in Android ListView?

Tags: android

I have Android ListView that holding some items, the flow that I'am trying to do:

1. Select first item
2. Highlight item
3. move to next item
4. do step 2
5. Loop step 2 and 3 until last step

the only input from user is to start the above flow.

The list is actually steps that holding HTTP requests, when the user click on play button, the steps inside the list will be executed one after one until all the list will be done,
while the list is being played, I need to highlight each item.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you can try the following code:

```
  int itemsInList=myList.getAdapter().getCount();
  for(int i=1;i<itemsInList;i++){
      myList.setSelection(i);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

put alert telling user you need to select the item......that's what you need to do...

for alert you can show `toast` or `alertdialog`

that's what r asking?